# Getting "The operation is not valid for the state of the transaction.", but I'm not using a transaction

Tags: linq-to-sql, transactions

```
Stack Trace:    at System.Transactions.TransactionState.EnlistPromotableSinglePhase(InternalTransaction tx, IPromotableSinglePhaseNotification promotableSinglePhaseNotification, Transaction atomicTransaction)
  at System.Transactions.Transaction.EnlistPromotableSinglePhase(IPromotableSinglePhaseNotification promotableSinglePhaseNotification)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.EnlistNonNull(Transaction tx)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.Enlist(Transaction tx)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.Activate(Transaction transaction)
  at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.ActivateConnection(Transaction transaction)
  at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)
  at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
  at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
  at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlConnectionManager.UseConnection(IConnectionUser user)
  at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.get_IsSqlCe()
  at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.InitializeProviderMode()
  at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
  at System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[S](Expression expression)
  at System.Linq.Queryable.All[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
```

I'm not using a transaction or `TransactionScope` at this point. Does a transaction get created automatically by the framework if one doesn't exist, or is a transaction sneaking in from somewhere?

This is C# .NET 4, querying against MS SQL 2008 using LINQ-to-SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ to SQL creates a transaction when you do SaveChanges so that the commit is atomic - i.e. either all changes save or none.

Answer (score 1):

While not an alternate answer I wanted to expand on this as I have just experienced this issue with my own app.

I have an ASP.Net application that uses the .Net 4.0 framework and I am seeing the same callstack and exception, at least from SqlConnection.Open() onwards. The exception takes a while to occur, a hour of 20+ users accessing the application is normally enough to trigger it. However, the root cause of the exception is potentially different to the OP's.

What I have found is that the exception is being thrown because the worker thread processing the ASP.Net request contains an ambient transaction that is referencing a transaction that has previously aborted and is being cleared up by the Finalizer thread. Essentially the code that created the transaction did not dispose of it thus it's down to the Finalizer to clean up the resources. The problem is that the ambient transaction for the worker thread does not get cleared until the Finalzer has done its thing. This means future requests that execute on the thread before the Finalizer completes will enlist in this already aborted transaction (auto enlist has to be enabled unless you specifically enlist).

The root cause for this issue was a nightmare to track down so hopefully if someone hits the same issue they will not spend over a week up to their eyeballs in good old WinDbg like I have just done :)